# Celery - Flower service in Cent/7 doesn't show data after a restart

Tags: python, celery, centos7, supervisord, flower

My service is as below :

```
[Service]
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/celery -A tasks /usr/bin/flower --port=5000 --basic_auth=sun:flower --persistent=true --/var/log/supervisord.log
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple
```

I have created a simple tasks for testing purposes after creating a REDIS master-slave replication and pointing Celery and flower to Master...

**celery.ini** for Supervisord

```
[program:SPSimpleTasks]
directory = /home/vagrant/
command = celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=DEBUG -n SimpleTasks
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
```

**celery_app.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://:<PASSWORD>@192.168.100.20:6379/0')
#app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
app.conf.update(
    enable_utc          =   True,
    broker_url          =   'redis://:<PASSWORD>@192.168.100.20:6379/0',
    result_backend      =   'redis://:<PASSWORD>@192.168.100.20:6379/1',
    result_persistent   =   True,
    task_serializer     =   'json',
    result_serializer   =   'json',
    accept_content      =   ['json']
)
```

Again, the workers are working fine and flower shows the tasks result. But once I restart the service using

> sudo service flower restart

Flower loads as its brand new install without any data...

Am I doing something wrong with the broker / backend urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well It was an additional change to the configuration in Flower and I changed the approach a bit!

The required config property was **db**

I updated the service to

**/etc/systemd/system/flower.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Flower Celery Service

[Service]
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/flower --/var/log/supervisord.log
Restart=on-failure
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/home/vagrant/flowerconfig.py**

```
port        =   5000
broker      =   'redis://:<password>@192.168.100.20:6379/0'
broker_api  =   'redis://:<password>@192.168.100.20:6379/0'
basic_auth  =   ['sun:flower']
persistent  =   True
db          =   '/home/vagrant/flower.db'
```

After providing the **db** property, it was all fine. Except for one issue.. the Flower Dashboard was not showing data but the Tasks page was loading the tasks list prior to the refresh!

Learnt from http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#db

> A database file to use if persistent mode is enabled (by default,
>   db=flower)

I've submitted the same as issue / observation in flower -- https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/787

Hope this helps to other facing similar issue!!